# Prevent publishing the post before setting a featured image?

Tags: plugins, functions, post-thumbnails, publish

As the title says , I want a plugin/function to prevent/inform the user when he tries to publish the post without setting the featured image.

ANY HELP ???

Answer (score 4):

The `has_post_thumbnail()` works for me, in WP versions 3.4.1 and other most recently.
But in this logic, because the WP will publish the post even with `exit` or `wp_die()` or anything to terminate the PHP script. For prevent that the post stay with published status, you will need to update the post before terminate. Look the code below:

```
add_action('save_post', 'prevent_post_publishing', -1);
function prevent_post_publishing($post_id)
{
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    // You also add a post type verification here,
    // like $post->post_type == 'your_custom_post_type'
    if($post->post_status == 'publish' && !has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) {
        $post->post_status = 'draft';
        wp_update_post($post);

        $message = '<p>Please, add a thumbnail!</p>'
                 . '<p><a href="' . admin_url('post.php?post=' . $post_id . '&action=edit') . '">Go back and edit the post</a></p>';
        wp_die($message, 'Error - Missing thumbnail!');
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// Something like that should help, but you'll have to play with it to get it working:
// inside your functions.php file
function wpse16372_prevent_publish()
{
    if ( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    // This should be ok, but should be tested:
    $post_id = $GLOBALS['post']->ID;
    echo '<pre>Test for post ID: '; print_r( $post_id ); echo '</pre>';// the actual test

    // has_post_thumbnail() doesn't work/exist on/for admin screens (see your error msg). You need to find another way to test if the post has a thumbnail. Maybe some Javascript?
    //if ( ! has_post_thumbnail( $post_id );
    if ( ! has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) )
    {
        ?>
        <!-- // 
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert( 'you have to use a featured image' );
        </script>
        // -->
        <?php
        exit; // abort
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse16372_prevent_publish', 100 );
?>
```

Comment: But it could be that the `has_post_thumbnail` won't work if it hasn't already got one. I asume that `save_post` doesn't get fired on `publish_post` hook.

Comment: That is a pretty neat idea.  Could it be modified to simply "Alert" vs. aborting or not-publishing the post?  I'd like something to come up if the client forgets, but don't necessarily want to stop anything from being saved.

Comment: Oh, it already alerts and then aborts (in case js is not activated).

Comment: Thanks a lot Kaiser for your help, but whenever I try to paste the code and log in to admin panel it gives this error
Parse error: syntax error
for the line
if ( ! has_post_thumbnail( $GLOBALS['post']->ID );

Can you help me ?

Comment: see update/edit of A. Btw: I already mentioned in my comment, that "it could be that `has_post_thumbnail` won't work". You will have to search for an alternative or maybe intercept on `$_POST` and check what you got there. Then decide whether to alert & abort or not. Search for the hooks. I'm sorry, but i can't be of more help.